# Solving A Double Summation

Tags: summation

I came across this problem in my textbook: $\sum_{i=10}^{n+10}\sum_{j=i}^{n+10} j$, I know how to do a double summation but not one where they are linked at the starting points like this.  The textbook says to write this summation as a function of n.  It says to write this summation as a function of n, using summations that have already been proven such as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i$ = $n*(n+1)/2$

Comment: Could you express $\sum_{j=12}^{n+10}j$ in closed form as a function of $n$?

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal? For example, the [Hockey-Stick Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) can be used to handle these kinds of formulas compactly.

Comment: I think what Brian and I are asking is that you provide some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) to allow us to help you.

Comment: It says to write this summation as a function of n, using summations that have already been proven such as$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} i$ is $(n)*(n+1)/2$

Comment: $$\sum _{i=10}^{n+10} \left(\sum _{j=i}^{n+10} j\right)=\frac{1}{3} (n+1) (n+2) (n+15)$$

Comment: @BobJoe: The proper place for context is in the question. Often people who flag or vote-to-close because of lack of context, don't look at the comments. Mentioning what formulas you have proven that might be applicable would also be useful.

Comment: @Raffaele what were the steps to get the final answer! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of an arithmetic progression is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum)
$$\sum _{j=\text{start}}^{\text{end}} j=\frac{1}{2} (\text{end}-\text{start}+1) (\text{end}+\text{start})$$
Thus from the inner sum you get
$$\sum _{j=i}^{n+10} j=\frac{1}{2} (11-i+n) (10+i+n)=-\frac{i^2}{2}+\frac{i}{2}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{21 n}{2}+55$$
To compute the outer sum we have to compute the following
$$\sum _{i=10}^{n+10} \left(\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{21 n}{2}+55\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sum _{i=10}^{n+10} i-\frac{1}{2} \sum _{i=10}^{n+10} i^2$$
The first sum is simply $(n+1)$ times the argument
$$\sum _{i=10}^{n+10} \left(\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{21 n}{2}+55\right)=(n+1) \left(\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{21 n}{2}+55\right)$$
The second can be solved with the formula above
$$\frac{1}{2} \sum _{i=10}^{n+10} i=\frac{1}{4} (n+1) (n+20)$$
For the third sum we need the formula to sum squares
$$\sum _{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1)$$
Notice that
$$\sum _{i=10}^{n+10} i^2=\sum _{i=1}^{n+10} i^2-\sum _{i=1}^9 i^2$$
Thus

$$\sum _{i=10}^{n+10} i^2=\frac{1}{6} (n+10) (n+11) (2 n+21)-285=\frac{1}{6} (n+1) \left(2 n^2+61 n+600\right)$$
Putting all together

$$\sum _{j=i}^{n+10} j=(n+1) \left(\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{21 n}{2}+55\right)+\frac{1}{4} (n+1) (n+20)-\frac{1}{12} (n+1) \left(2 n^2+61 n+600\right)=\\=(n+1) \left(\left(\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{21 n}{2}+55\right)-\frac{1}{12} \left(2 n^2+61 n+600\right)+\frac{n+20}{4}\right)=\\=(n+1)\left(\frac{n^2}{3}+\frac{17 n}{3}+10\right)=\frac{1}{3} (n+1)(n+2) (n+15)$$
And finally we get
$$\sum_{i=10}^{n+10}\sum_{j=i}^{n+10} j=\frac{1}{3} (n+1)(n+2) (n+15)$$
This is the reason why using a CAS can be useful and time saving :)